# Magento-Change Attribute of All Products

Tags: sql, magento, attributes

I have created a Yes/No attribute in Magento with default value of "No". I have more 100+ products and changing the value of this attribute to "Yes" of each product separately is a pain.

Is there any other way suing MySql or SSH to change this attribute of all products to "Yes" altogether?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the admin, go to Catalog -> Manage Products, select the products from the grid for which you want to update your attribute. Then from the right side where it says Actions: select "Update Attributes" and click "Submit". Then change the attribute and click save, all of the products will be updated at once.