# How we can add attributes for old product in Magento?

Tags: magento, attributes

I have Magento portal and I want to filter option through the attributes. So is there any possibility to add the attributes for old product which already in portal?

Comment: There is no proper information. why do you want to add an attribute? Can't you access them from admin panel?

Comment: Hi Shivannd, I want to create product  filter option so with the attributes it can be possible. Please suggest some best way to solve this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure can add attributes for existing attributes.

go to `catalog > Manage attributes > create new attribute` and than go for `Attribute set` and drag the new attribute to attribute set.

than you can give attribute values for each products manually or for all products once using "update attributes" option.

than you can display the attributes under layered navigation.

feel free to ask any doubts

Comment: Thanks for your response!!  Actually in the beginning I didn't add any attributes and same not assigned to products. So if I want to create fresh attributes then it will be possible to assign individually for all the products.

Comment: Thats absolutely fine, you can add it in any time. and if you have common attribute values, dont assign manually by opening each products.

Comment: instead use "update attributes" , go to catalog > Manage prodcucts > than select the products you want to give atttribute values and than you can see this http://prnt.sc/ay6wy8 "select update attributes and than give value and save it

Comment: follow @zokibtmkd answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226040/magento-change-attribute-of-all-products

Answer (score 1):

For the older product I have added the attributes and include in the default attribute set. So it will be by default add for all the products only you have to select for each product.

Please find the relevant image: [image]